# How to check wso2 identity server has completely started or not using batch file.

Tags: batch-file, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can I track wso2 identity server has started or not in batch file.

In my project, I am using **wso2is-5.2** as a identity server. To start my project and wso2is, I have created window services and both start automatically. **I want to set dependence between these services, so that, my project window service call only when wso2is has started completely**.

Comment: I have no idea what a wso2 server is :) Is it a program running on your device to setup a local server or is it an actual server with an IP adress. How could you check if the server has started or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait till the port 9443 is open.

Comment: Should it be something like - @echo off
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 9443
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (wait) ELSE (call my application)

Comment: Not sure whether that is sufficient. Could you start it and check what the status is when it is fully started? I have the status `waiting` for something and That could not be correct. But the basic script would be correct, yes.